# How to Find a tag without specific attribute using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the content of the 'p' tags that didn't have the specific attribute.

I have some tags with 'class'='cost', and some tags with 'class'='cost' and 'itemprop'='price'

```
all_cars = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'listdata'})
...
...
tatal_cost= car.findChildren('p', attrs={'class': 'cost'})
cost= car.findChildren('p', attrs={'class': 'cost', 'itemprop':'price'})
```

I am trying to find 'p' tags without 'itemprop' attribute, but i cant find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeautifulSoup lets you define a function and pass it into its `find_all()` method:

```
def has_class_but_not_itemprop(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('itemprop')

# Pass this function into find_all() and you’ll pick up all the <p> 
# tags you're after:

soup.find_all(has_class_but_not_itemprop)
# [<p class="cost">...</p>,
#  <p class="cost">...</p>,
#  <p class="cost">...</p>]
```

For more information, see the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

Comment: I don’t think there’s any benefit to doing it this way rather than by using `soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'cost', 'itemprop':None})` or equivalently `soup.find_all('p', class_='cost', itemprop=None)` — is there? (Obviously the function’s more flexible, so good to fall back on, but matching `None` is simpler _and_ benchmarks faster than the function.) Edit: and I just noticed it’s [Bitto Bennichan’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163378/953104) below.

Answer (score 7):

BeautifulSoup's built-in attribute filters are enough for this. You can give `True` as value to simple check if the attribute is present. `None` can be used to specify that the attribute should not be present. Likewise the value can be any attribute value (eg 'cost').

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<p class="cost">paragraph 1</p>
<p class="cost">paragraph 2</p>
<p class="cost">paragraph 3</p>
<p class="cost" itemprop="1">paragraph 4</p>
<p class="somethingelse">paragraph 5</p>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print("---without 'itemprop' attribute")
print(soup.find_all('p',itemprop=None))
print("---with class = 'cost' and without 'itemprop' attribute----")
print(soup.find_all('p',attrs={'itemprop':None,"class":'cost'}))
#below is an alternative way to specify this
#print(soup.find_all('p',itemprop=None,class_='cost'))
```

Output

```
---without 'itemprop' attribute
[<p class="cost">paragraph 1</p>, <p class="cost">paragraph 2</p>, <p class="cost">paragraph 3</p>, <p class="somethingelse">paragraph 5</p>]
---with class = 'cost' and without 'itemprop' attribute----
[<p class="cost">paragraph 1</p>, <p class="cost">paragraph 2</p>, <p class="cost">paragraph 3</p>]
```